# Prestashop cms page json content

Tags: json, content-management-system, prestashop

I'm trying to get CMS page content from my friend's wordpress with api.
This works just fine and I can customise the content with css.

BUT I know you should NOT insert html inside controller, is there a way to do .tpl file for this which is then called for title and content 
OR
even better if you could somehow get this content to admin as well, but I think it is currently impossible ?

However, other cms pages should be working as normal.

I have currently in CmsController.php inside function initContent:

```
        if($this->cms->meta_title == 'mycmspage')
        {
          $ch = curl_init();
          $timeout = 5;
          $url = 'http://friendurl.com/wp-json/wp/v2/pages/xxx';
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
            $data = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);

          $obj = json_decode($data, TRUE);
          $this->cms->content = '<h2 class="myheader">'.$obj['title']['rendered'].'</h2><article class="myarticle">'. $obj['content']['rendered'].'</article>';
        }
```

using prestashop 1.6.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can set smarty variables and get template content.

```
$obj = json_decode($data, TRUE);
$this->context->smarty->assign(array(
    'mycms_title' => $obj['title']['rendered'],
    'mycms_content' => $obj['content']['rendered']
));
$this->cms->content = $this->context->smarty->fetch('path_to_your_tpl_file');
```

Something like this can be achieved with admin controllers as well. Depends on the type of admin page you are on (list, view, add, edit etc.) but by default it's a type of list. So you can override the `renderList()` method to display it.

```
AdminYourModController extends ModuleAdminController {
    public function renderList() {
        // your curl code
        $obj = json_decode($data, TRUE);
        $this->context->smarty->assign(array(
            'mycms_title' => $obj['title']['rendered'],
            'mycms_content' => $obj['content']['rendered']
        ));

        return $this->context->smarty->fetch('path_to_your_tpl_file');
    }
}
```

Comment: I have made file CmsController.php to override/controllers/front/ with the code you suggested, `class CmsControllerCoreOverride extends CmsControllerCore {` but somewhy it just loads the original CmsController.php from controllers folder which just works fine... ? I'm not sure if this is more wide problem with override but ?

Comment: Also, is there any other "more static" way to identify cmspage in code than `if($this->cms->meta_title == 'mycmspage')`. meta_title can be changed

Comment: If you wish to override core cms controller you need to declare `CmsController extends CmsControllerCore`. To uniquely identify cms page, you can only do it by its ID.